# Z-eigenvalue problem

Tags: numerics, eigenvalues

I am interested in solving an $N-$dimensional $Z-$eigenvalue problem, which schematically takes the following form

$$
\sum_{b=1,c=1}^{N}T_{abc} X_b X_c=\lambda\,X_a\quad \text{with}\quad \sum_{a=1}^NX_a\,X_a=1\,,
$$

where $T_{abc}$ is a symmetric three tensor, $\lambda$ is the $Z-$eigenvalue and $X_a$ its associated $Z-$eigenvector. `Matlab` has a routine for solving this type of problem, but is incredibly slow (particularly because I am interested in cases where $N$ is about $25$ or so).

I have implemented a simple `FindRoot` algorithm to find some particular solutions for $(\lambda,X)$, but I am interested to know if a numerical method exists where one can compute the smallest $n$ positive $Z-$eigenvalues $\lambda$. Ideally, $n$ is of order $10$.

Comment: It is easy to implement an iterative method, where one starts from a guess vector, computes $\sum_bT_{abc}X_{b}$, solves the eigenvalue problem, and repeats the process until convergence. Some mixing scheme should be employed to avoid flipping of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, this is a good method to find a solution. However, I would like to know if a method exists that finds all solutions.

Comment: Just for people who may wonder how many eigenvalues are expected at all.  As is shown by Cartwright, D. and Sturmfels, B., 2013. The number of eigenvalues of a tensor. Linear algebra and its applications, 438(2), pp.942-952.(10.1016/j.laa.2011.05.040) for a tensor on rank $m$ with dimension $n$, there are  exactly $((m-1)^n-1)/(m-2)$ eigenvalues counted with multiplicity. Thus in the present case $m=3$, $n=25$ leading to 33554431 eigenvalues. I would say that to find all of them together with eigenvectors is a formidable endeavor.

Comment: The result of such calculation alone would take more than 6GB.

Comment: Indeed, this is a rather complicated task in general. However, even finding a method that would allow to track the lowest 20 eigenvalues would be interesting.

Comment: Yes, unlike typical matrix problems, [most tensor problems are NP-hard](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2512329). So, your expectations are unrealistic at the current level of mathematics. Of course, we do not know whether [P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). So, maybe there is some hope and  a US$1,000,000 prize :)